# python to C conversion error

Tags: python, c

python code

```
for b in range(4):
    for c in range(4):
        print myfunc(b/0x100000000, c*8)
```

c code

```
unsigned int b,c;
for(b=0;b<4;b++)
    for(c=0;c<4; c++)
    printf("%L\n", b/0x100000000);
    printf("%L\n" , myfunc(b/0x100000000, c*8));
```

I am getting an error saying:
error: integer constant is too large for "long" type at both printf statement in c code.
'myfunc' function returns a long.
This can be solved by defining 'b' a different type. I tried defining 'b' as 'long' and 'unsigned long' but no help.
Any pointers?

---

My bad...This is short version of problem

```
unsigned int b;
b = 1;
printf("%L", b/0x100000000L);
```

I am getting error and warnings:
error: integer constant is too large for "long" type
warning: conversion lacks type at end of format
warning: too many arguments for format

Comment: You're missing some curly braces in your C code.

Comment: For long integer constants use `0x100000000L`

Comment: What output are you expecting here? Any integer type divided by a larger value is just going to be zero.

Answer (score 3):

Your C code needs braces to create the scope that Python does by indentation, so it should look like this:

```
unsigned int b,c;
for(b=0;b<4;b++)
{
    for(c=0;c<4; c++)
    {
      printf("%L\n", b/0x100000000);
      printf("%L\n" , myfunc(b/0x100000000, c*8)); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `long long`. Python automatically uses number representation which fits your constants, but C does not. 0x100000000L simply does not fit in 32-bit `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` and so on. Also, read your C textbook on `long long` data type and working with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int b,c;
const unsigned long d = 0x100000000L; /* 33 bits may be too big for int */

for(b=0;b<4;b++) {
    for(c=0;c<4; c++) { /* use braces and indent consistently */
        printf("%ud\n", b/d); /* "ud" to print Unsigned int in Decimal */
        printf("%ld\n", myfunc(b/d, c*8));  /* "l" is another modifier for "d" */
    }
}
```